# i can't log in through subdomain

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-login

I am trying to log in a user by sending a POST request to my API where `Flask-Login` extension doing the authorization process.

The API is on a separated subdomain **api.local.products** , here are the configurations of **/etc/hosts** on my machine also the extension configuration:

```
192.168.0.108          local.products
192.168.0.108          .local.products
192.168.0.108          client.local.products
192.168.0.108          vendor.local.products
192.168.0.108          api.local.products

REMEMBER_COOKIE_NAME = 'products.remember'
REMEMBER_COOKIE_SECURE = None
REMEMBER_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
REMEMBER_COOKIE_REFRESH_EACH_REQUEST = True
REMEMBER_COOKIE_DOMAIN = '.local.products'

SESSION_COOKIE_NAME = 'products.store'
SESSION_TYPE = 'sqlalchemy'
SESSION_KEY_PREFIX = 'products.store'
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = '.local.products'

SESSION_PERMANENT = False
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SESSION_SQLALCHEMY = SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME = timedelta(days=15)
```

**api.py**

```
@api_route.route('/user-login', methods=['POST'])
def user_login():
    data = request.get_json()

    login = data['user_login']
    password = data['user_password'].encode('utf-8')

    get_user = Users.query.filter(or_(Users.email == login, Users.telephone == login)).first()

    if get_user:

        if get_user.check_password(password):

            if 'remember_me' in data:
                login_user(get_user, remember=True)
            else:
                login_user(get_user, remember=False)

            identity_changed.send(
                current_app._get_current_object(),
                identity=Identity(get_user.id)
            )

            return jsonify({'success': create_html_object.generate_html_template(), 'redirect': next_ or url_for('client.index', _external=True)+ f'#{get_user.public_id}' })
        else:
            return jsonify({'error': 'Username or Password is wrong!'})

    else:
        return jsonify({'error': 'Error happened!'})
```

The user actually can't login, i can't get the **current_user** object, in fact i am getting a **200** response without any error, also i tried using `session['user_logged'] = get_user.public_id` and after i get a success message that the user logged in, the value of **user_logged** after redirection is `None`

I forgot to mention that, if i set the API as a path not subdomain, the login process works!

Comment: Are you accessing the API over HTTPS? As the SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True flag is set, cookies won't be sent unless the API is accessed over HTTPS

Comment: @MattHealy Yes i am, the flag set to true and my website runing with SSL certificate.